# Create bookmark on homescreen from webpage

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, bookmarks

I am attempting to create a shortcut to a webpage / bookmark on the home screen when a user clicks a button on our web page (they will be viewing it through their mobile browser).

At the moment I am just looking at iOS and Android. I know the user can do this themselves via the bookmark menu but we are attempting to make it easier for our users.

I found this question: [How to add android bookmark on homescreen from web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131904/how-to-add-android-bookmark-on-homescreen-from-web-page)
but it as it is from 2012, I was hoping that someone would have found a way or have advice on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance,